# Добавление элемента в вектор приводит к ошибке

Tags: c++, vector, mfc

Пишу приложение с использованием библиотеки MFC. По нажатию на кнопку "Добавить" должно происходить добавление обьекта в вектор. И оно происходит, до того момента когда количество элементов в векторе доходит до 23-25 элемента. Точки останова почти всегда указывают на разные места класса Abonent. Так же себя ведет и обычный динамический массив через new[]. Если грузить 100 обьектов циклом, то никаких проблем, но как только начинаешь добавлять через кнопку обьект, через 2-3 обьекта приложение падает.

Прошу помощи.

Обнаружил следующее:
Если в кнопке оставить только добавление обьекта, обьекты добавляются. то точка останова появляется где то на 225 обьектах. и точка остановки INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();

```
void CPhonebookDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    
    Abonent newAbonent;
    massAb.AddAbToMas(newAbonent);
}
```

Как только добавляю отрисовку обьектов в ListControl, падает на 37 добавлении.
Точка останова ставиться в разные места,например:

```
name = obj.GetName();
```

или

```
m_ListCtrl.SetItemText(nItem, 5, debet);
```

или

```
nItem = m_ListCtrl.InsertItem(0, id);
```

И каждый раз что то новое.

```
void CPhonebookDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    m_ListCtrl.DeleteAllItems();
    Abonent newAbonent;
    
    massAb.AddAbToMas(newAbonent);
    std::vector<Abonent> arr = massAb.ReturnMassObj();
    CString id, surname, name, patronymic, address, debet, credit;

    for (Abonent obj : arr) {
        int nItem;
        Abonent* pAbonent = &obj;
        id.Format(L"%d", obj.getId());
        surname = obj.GetSurname();
        name = obj.GetName();
        patronymic = obj.GetPatronymic();
        address = obj.GetAddress();
        debet.Format(L"%d", obj.GetDebet());
        credit.Format(L"%d", obj.GetCredit());
        nItem = m_ListCtrl.InsertItem(0, id);
        m_ListCtrl.SetItemText(nItem, 1, surname);
        m_ListCtrl.SetItemText(nItem, 2, name);
        m_ListCtrl.SetItemText(nItem, 3, patronymic);
        m_ListCtrl.SetItemText(nItem, 4, address);
        m_ListCtrl.SetItemText(nItem, 5, debet);
        m_ListCtrl.SetItemText(nItem, 6, credit);
        //m_ListCtrl.SetItemData(nItem, (DWORD_PTR)pAbonent);

    }
}
```

Abonent.cpp

```
private:
    int Id;
    CString Surname;
    CString Name;
    CString Patronymic;
    CString Address;
    CString CreditCardNum;
    int Debet;
    int Credit;
    int TimeCityCalls;
    int TimeInterCityCalls;


#include "pch.h"
#include "Abonent.h"
#include "PhonebookDlg.h"
 int s_genId = 1;// переменная для генерации уикальных ИД

Abonent::Abonent()
{
    Id = 0;
    Surname = "";
    Name = "";
    Patronymic = "";
    Address = " ";
    CreditCardNum = " ";
    Debet = 0;
    Credit = 0;
    TimeCityCalls = 0;
    TimeInterCityCalls = 1;
    
}
Abonent::~Abonent()
{
    
}
//гетеры и сетеры
int Abonent::getId() {
    return Id;
}
void Abonent::SetId(int value) {
    Id = value;
}

void Abonent::SetSurname(CString value) {
    Surname = value;
}
CString Abonent::GetSurname() {
    return Surname;
}

CString Abonent::GetName() {
    return Name;
}
void Abonent::SetName(CString value) {
    Name = value;
}

CString Abonent::GetPatronymic() {
    return Patronymic;
}
void Abonent::SetPatronymic(CString value) {
    Patronymic = value;
}

CString Abonent::GetAddress() {
    return Address;
}
void Abonent::SetAddress(CString value) {
    Address = value;
}

CString Abonent::GetCreditCardNum() {
    return CreditCardNum;
}
void Abonent::SetCreditCardNum(CString value) {
    CreditCardNum = value;
}

int Abonent::GetDebet() {
    return Debet;
}
void Abonent::SetDebet(int value) {
    Debet = value;
}

int Abonent::GetCredit() {
    return Credit;
}
void Abonent::SetCredit(int value) {
    Credit = value;
}

int Abonent::GetTimeCityCalls() {
    return TimeCityCalls;
}
void Abonent::SetTimeCityCalls(int value) {
    TimeCityCalls = value;
}

int Abonent::GetTimeInterCityCalls() {
    return TimeInterCityCalls;
}
void Abonent::SetTimeInterCityCalls(int value) {
    TimeInterCityCalls = value;
}

void Abonent::GenID()
{
    Id = s_genId++;
}


CString Abonent::ConvertTimeIntToStr(int ms)
{   
    
    int H, M, S; //D;
    int timeSec = ms;
    M = timeSec / 60; //Общее кол-во минут
    S = timeSec - (M * 60);//Количество секунд
    H = M / 60;//Кколичество часов
    M = M - (H * 60);// Количество минут
    CString tme;
    tme.Format(L"%d:%d:%d",H,M,S);
    return tme;
}

int Abonent::ConvertTimeStrToInt()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Класс для хранения массива обьектов:

```
class MasivAbonentov
{
public:
    MasivAbonentov();
    ~MasivAbonentov();
    int GetCount();
    void SetCount(int);
    void AddAbToMas(Abonent obj);
    void DelAbToMas(int IdObj);
    
    void LoadArr(Abonent*);
    std::vector<Abonent> ReturnMassObj();
private:
    std::vector<Abonent> massiv;
    int count;
};


#include "pch.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include "MasivAbonentov.h"
int count = 0;
MasivAbonentov::MasivAbonentov()
{
    
    
}

MasivAbonentov::~MasivAbonentov()
{

}

int MasivAbonentov::GetCount()
{
    return count;
}

void MasivAbonentov::SetCount(int n)
{
    count = n;
}

void MasivAbonentov::AddAbToMas(Abonent obj)
{   
    massiv.push_back(obj);
    count++;        
}

void MasivAbonentov::DelAbToMas(int IdObj)
{

    std::vector<Abonent>::iterator it;
    it = massiv.begin();
    while (it != massiv.end()) {
        if (it->getId() == IdObj) {
            massiv.erase(it);
        }
    }
    
}

void MasivAbonentov::LoadArr(Abonent* arr)
{
    //delete[] massiv;
    //massiv = arr;
}

std::vector<Abonent> MasivAbonentov::ReturnMassObj()
{
    return massiv;
}
```

Описание класса Абонент:

```
class Abonent
{
public:
    Abonent();
    ~Abonent();

    int getId();
    void SetId(int value);
    
    CString GetSurname();
    void SetSurname(CString value);

    CString GetName();
    void SetName(CString value);

    CString GetPatronymic();
    void SetPatronymic(CString value);

    CString GetAddress();
    void SetAddress(CString value);

    CString GetCreditCardNum();
    void SetCreditCardNum(CString value);

    int GetDebet();
    void SetDebet(int value);

    int GetCredit();
    void SetCredit(int value);

    int GetTimeCityCalls();
    void SetTimeCityCalls(int value);

    int GetTimeInterCityCalls();
    void SetTimeInterCityCalls(int value);
    void GenID();

    CString ConvertTimeIntToStr(int ms);
    int ConvertTimeStrToInt();

private:
    int Id;
    CString Surname;
    CString Name;
    CString Patronymic;
    CString Address;
    CString CreditCardNum;
    int Debet;
    int Credit;
    int TimeCityCalls;
    int TimeInterCityCalls; 

};
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117355/discussion-on-question-by-kik1-------).

Answer (score 0):

Создал новый проект, подключил свои классы. Проблема исчезла. Что было, сказать не могу. Многих поставило в тупик.